# Streaming webcam video to IIS Live Smooth Streaming Publishing Point

Tags: silverlight, iis, live-streaming, smooth-streaming

Are there any tutorials on how to capture webcam video and send it to IIS live smooth streaming publishing point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very easy: 
First off - you need to install Expression Encoder 4 PRO on the PC where your webcam is working (note that the evaluation version for Expression 4 PRO doesn't enables to work in smooth streaming so you must obtain the PRO version).

After you setup a publishing Point at the IIS server - you need to copy the URL of the ISML to the "Publishing point" field under the "Output" tab in the Expression Encoder 4 PRO.

I guess you know how to configure the encoding bitrates. Let me know if not.

After that simply click Start and that's all. you can start watching the Live video on the Silverlight by applying the URLS to the same ISML you gave the Encoder.

Moshe

Comment: Are there any free alternatives to the Expression Encoder 4 pro version?

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the encoder? Flash can do this by sending to FMS or Red5...